# Amplfying MCU 113kHz output

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, logic-level, esp32

I am using an ESP32 to generate a 113 kHz, ~3,5 V output. I then intend to amplify this to a ~50V peak-peak waveform. For that I am trying to use a DC-DC converter based on the LM2577 (to boost from 12 V to 50 V) and the Logic Level MOSFET IRLZ44N.

The DC-DC part seems to be working fine, as I can get a 50 V output. However, once I connect the output of the ESP32 to the IRLZ44N (like the diagram below) I cannot get a waveform at the output, just a 50V DC voltage. Is anything wrong with the circuit?

The IRLZ44N seems to be working fine. Below is also a picture of the ESP32 output from the oscilloscope. From what I've been reading, the current source capacity of the ESP32 is 40mA (I am not sure this is true for the LED PWM output I am using, this might be the problem). Cout = 220uF electrolytic.

Will appreciate some feedback. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the MOSFET part number and what value resistor in drain?

Comment: Your microcontroller may not have enough drive strength to charge and discharge the gate. This is what dedicated gate drivers are for...

Comment: Is the oscilloscope waveform shown with the mosfet connected?

Comment: @Andyaka The MOSFET part number isth IRLZ44N. The resisor in drain I used 40k.

Comment: @MarcoZollinger the oscilloscope waveform is shown with the MOSFET connected, but at the output pin of the ESP32

Comment: If you set the ESP32 pin to a permanent high level, does the mosfet turn on and pull the output low? Are the ESP32 and mosfet grounds connected? Can you post a picture of your circuit?

Comment: @MarcoZollinger I tried setting the ESP32 pin to permanent high and indeed the MOSFET turns on and pulls the output low. The ESP32 and MOSFET grounds are connected together. 
I tried setting the ESP low 3 seconds and hight 3 seconds and everything seems to work. I suppose the ESP can't source the current for driving the MOSFET gate at these frequencies. I will try to get a logic level gate driver. Any easily available cheap gate driver off the top of your head?
Thank you for the help!

Comment: Maybe take a look at the MCP1407 if you want something cheap in a through hole package. Power it off the 12V rail. Could be a good match for your circuit, didn't look too close though. But there should be plenty of alternatives.

Comment: @MarcoZollinger I got an MCP1407. First picture below shows the output of the driver, which feeds the MOSFET. However, I still can't get a nice ~50V 113kHz output signal. 2nd picture shows the waveform of the MOSFET drain to Ground. There is a 113kHZ signal, but not 50V amplitude. I also added a 0.1uF ceramic capacitor in parallel with the electrolytic. The other 2 pictures are the circuit. Any ideas? Thanks!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytTgy.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJmEH.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqHcn.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihmbv.jpg